# My question with a bounty got an autoselected answer that (almost) misses the point completly

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, moderators

I did put up a question for bounty [Get the z-Buffer in 16 bit resolution in 3ds max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406820/get-the-z-buffer-in-16-bit-resolution-in-3ds-max) , which got one answer, which kinda led in the right direction, but had an immense flaw (Still in 8 Bit). I upvoted the answer cause the direction it was going is correct, but it was not totally solved, so I did not accept it. However, it was upvoted a second time, thus the bounty was auto selected in a case where the answer was not answering the question.

I know that it is not possible to withdraw a bounty which was put up once, however it feels kinda unfair to give the bounty to an unsatisfying answer.

So what could have been done better? Can a Mod change this? Or should the general behaviour of bounty questions be changed?

Comment: I agree the answer look like a comment in your case, but he tried to help in comment after on that answer. Before the bounty end a flag not an answer flag should had been done maybe in that case

Comment: Ah Thank your really much, I did not thought about flaggin it that way, that's good tip for the next time

Comment: @yagmoth555 but that was an answer, and even useful. NAA flag is plain wrong in such case. (As any flag, It's a valid answer.)

Comment: I totally disagree with "feels kinda unfair to give the bounty to an unsatisfying answer" - why unfair?? To whom? Someone spent time answering, they deserve a reward. Period. (If someone else will spend more time and write a better answer, their answer will be accepted or get more upvotes, thus getting the bounty.)

Comment: Maybe don't upvote answers that don't solve the problem completely? There is no time limit on casting upvotes, you could have posted a comment encouraging the poster to improve his answer. It is also not clear what is unfair here. If nobody had posted an answer, that bounty would have been lost and you wouldn't even have got that hint in the "right direction". A bounty is like a freebie coupon, it brings some customers to your business, you cannot really say it is unfair someone took the freebie without buying much else.

Comment: Maybe unfair was not the right phrasing. The Time spend on that answer was honsetly not that much worth the bounty. But I get your point. The answer simply gave a suggestion which did not work. It was a suggestion worth looking out for, but not worth  the bounty. Nevertheless, again, I get your points, and only wanted to know what to do to avoid such an unhappy endproduct. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Well, in a sense, the point of a bounty is to get attention more than anything else. On the other hand, its a little unfair to let someone set a bounty, and refuse to give it to anyone. Essentially *as long as someone posts a decent answer* and there's no explicit bounty awarded, the half bounty awarded is a bit of a wooden spoon prize.

All [this is in the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Making it better? Maybe allowing for a top-up to the next allowed level for extending the bounty would be an idea but as long as you got answers after you set a bounty, you got your money's (or reputation's worth).

Comment: This “wooden spoon prize” is a fantastic turn of phrase. Is it common where you’re from? Where are you from? Do you happen to know its origins, or, more precisely, are you aware of any contests where the consolation prize is a wooden spoon?

Comment: [The wooden spoon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_spoon_(award)). @DanBron

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm pretty certain that I picked it up from the sports pages on my local newspaper.